# hover over an image to display a bigger one next to it. Angular 7

Tags: angular, hover, angular7

[image]Hey I am trying to create a component that acts same like an amazon component. When you have multiple images on left side and you hover over them to see bigger one next to them.

My approach was to have a (mouseenter) event which calls a function with $event in it. And function sets variable {{image}}

So HTML i have is:

```
 <img width="100px;" id="div1" src="./assets/Capture.PNG" (mouseenter)="displayId($event)"/>
 <img width="100px;" id="div2" src="./assets/media.jpg" (mouseenter)="displayId($event)"/>

 <p>{{image}}</p>
```

and .ts is:

```
displayId(event: Event){
  this.image = event.target;
}
```

I know there is a better and simple approach I am just new to html so do not have that much knowledge.

When i try it gives me this. [obectHTMLImageElement]

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`mouseover`** instead of mouseenter

```
 <img width="100px;" id="div1" src="./assets/Capture.PNG" (mouseover)="displayId($event)"/>
```

and in TS

```
over(){
   this.image = event.target.source;
}
```

Comment: thank you... but final goal is to achieve a view of the photo next to the list of photos like in amazon when you view a product.

Comment: did not help because it is not displaying the image buddy lol... it is just a console.log() statement

Comment: you have to do the same what you did in the mouseenter

Comment: You can check my updated question with photo. I am getting that when I do it.

Comment: try with this  this.image = event.target.source;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182307/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ash).

Comment: so it works with: image: String,                                                                    
   over(event: Event){
  console.log(event);
  this.image =  (<HTMLImageElement>event.srcElement).src;

}